# Do I mention that I was an adjunct on my CV

Tags: cv, titles, adjunct-faculty, instructor

I am currently an adjunct professor.

I'm wondering how to best label this on my CV.

Specifically, should I use "Adjunct Professor", "instructor", "instructor of record", etc. as my job title?

- I think *adjunct* (unfortunately) has a negative connotation associated with it, so I'm worried that my experience will be devalued if I include *adjunct* in my job title/description.
- Does using just "Professor" imply that I am a full -time tenured professor?

So what is the best way to go about titling my adjunct position at this institution on my CV?

Comment: I teach at the best school in my field and even our students are having trouble getting tt jobs and are stuck in adjunct and Postdoc hell. There's no shame in being an adjunct, it's just how this horrible academic job market is.

Answer (score 7):

Use the job title assigned to you by your institution.  You don't really have any choice about this.

If the nature or duties of your job were significantly different from what is usually understood by that title (in the culture of the university where you are applying), you can add a note of clarification.

*Adjunct Professor* is usually understood (in the US at least) to mean a non-tenure-track part-time teaching position in which you are instructor of record for your courses, and have minimal research or service requirements.  If that accurately describes your job, then you don't need to list anything more than the title.

The job title *Professor*, without any other adjectives, is understood to mean "full professor," a senior tenured position whose duties may include research and service as well as teaching.  Listing this as your position would be severely misleading and might be considered fraudulent.

It's true that the generic noun *professor* can be used to describe anyone who teaches at a university.  But a CV is expected to contain your specific job title, not a generic term describing your job.

Comment: It's also a bad idea to insinuate that you are currently having a significantly "better" post than what you are applying for. Presumably OP is on the market for TT jobs - then giving the impression that he already is a full prof. will not improve his chances.